# Booting problem with Lubuntu 16.04.4 on Netbook from External Hard drive

Tags: boot, lubuntu

My internal hard drive on my netbook is malfunctioning.  Therefore, I installed Lubuntu on an external hard drive.  I tested booting to it from my desktop PC and it booted fine.  I then tried it from the Netbook and it gives me the GRUB menu from the external hard drive, I choose the first Ubuntu option, and it goes to my internal hard drive.  I have the boot order set to the USB in the BIOS and have booted from USB fine other times.  My current workaround is to choose the Advanced Options, and the choose the second entry, labeled Recovery Mode.  Then, when I get to the next menu, I choose Normal or Restore (the first option, I can't remember what it is called).  I researched other postings on here and one suggested doing apt-get update, then upgrade, then install xserver-xorg-video-intel.  That gave me an error, stating that there were unmet dependencies and it left me with broken packages.

I hope I have covered everything.  I would be grateful for any suggestions.

UPDATE...I am thinking my assessment of the hard drive being bad may not have been correct.  I am wondering if I have either bad drivers or a bad video card.  I am going to try to install a different distro to test further.

Comment: Have you selected your external hard drive as the device to install bootloader?

Comment: Hi Pranal - thanks for the comment.  Yes, and it worked fine on another PC.  I think the OS was possibly corrupted as I have successfully installed a minimal Lubuntu on the internal hard drive, which I thought was fried.  I think my problem was software related and is solved now.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh!! Good to hear that